# I/O exception <java.net.SocketException> in Solr startup

Tags: java, solr, ioexception, socketexception

When I start up Solr, I get the following error 
 I/O exception  caught when connecting to https://localhost:;
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException:
Error construct:sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext

Did anyone ever come across the same issue before?

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to connect through HTTPS on localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect using http://localhost. You are using https and it requires proper certificates and extra configuration. For localhost http is ok but is high recommend that you use https on production.